# Sharepoint site "view as visitor" option?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, sharepoint-permissions, check-permissions

I want to test the different permission levels on my SharePoint site.

Is there a way for me as site owner to view my site with a different level of permission **without** logging in with another user? Like appending a string like *?viewAs=Visitor* or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Per my knowledge, there is no feature to provide view of another permission with simple URL change. You will need to use another user account to do so.